# Storage spike after enabling Query Insights

Tags: google-cloud-sql

Ever since I enabled the Query Insights feature, it consumed 10-20GB a day.
Is this the expected behaviour?
[image: See the storage graph]

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/insights-overview#storage) "Query Insights does not occupy any storage space in your Cloud SQL instance storage space". So, if you noticed that your Cloud SQL storage has increased a lot, this could be for a different reason.

-Did you enable [Point-in-time recovery](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/backup-recovery/pitr#disk-usage)? PITR uses write-ahead logs and if you enabled this feature, that could be the reason why of your increases.

-Have you used temporary tables and you are not deleted them?

If none of the above applies to you, I highly recommend you to [open a case](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/manage-cases#creating_cases) with GCP support team so that they take a look at your Cloud SQL instance.

Comment: PITR is disabled. I do not use anymore temp tables than usual. Also it seems that since I disabled Query Insights, there were no increases.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't open a case as I do not have a support plan with GCP.

Comment: In that case, I would recommend you to create an [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers). You can create it as private in order to provide your project ID and the GCP team can take a look to your instance.